# How can I handle caching an log4j HTTP appender in Java?

Tags: java, http, logging, log4j, appender

So I am writing an application that will accept log entries from many other applications.  We mostly use `log4j`.

Since these applications are on different machines, I wanted to have a web service that accepted POST'd data from each application.  At which we could then search, etc.

I realize there are services like Loggly that handle this but I want to write my own (mainly for our security purposes and company not liking log information on 3rd party providers).

Anyway, I successfully got my own custom HttpAppender to work.  So that each application would send the message to a web service.

But before I break out the champagne, I realize that a direct post over HTTP could be a bad thing because some of these apps generate MILLIONS of rows in the logs.  So the last thing I want is my HttpAppender bringing down some T1 line or something.

So my idea was to buffer the HTTP POST's somehow and then periodically send those buffers in a single post.  So fewer large posts vs many smaller posts.

Of course buffering in something like Reddis/memcached locally on the same machine would help but I have to assume that I can't use external caching (on the same server).  So I would have to cache in the appender's memory/process.

Am I on the write track with buffering these HTTP posts?  Or, should I write the buffers to log files and then periodically post those log files?

Comment: Caching (not persisting the log entry immediately) is contrary to most log systems: it would hinder your ability to investigate crashes (most important logs lost) and weaken tamper-proofing. Having said that, log4j has a buffered fileappender, you could start looking there.

Comment: Buffered fillappender?  Yeah, I will definitely look at that.  The reason I wanted to cache log entries was to keep http posts to a minimum.  Ie, not doing an http post for every entry.  Also, this custom appender would run alongside the normal fileappenders that we use.  So local logging would still be there.  I'm just duplicating it over http to a remote server for analysis.  Thanks.

Comment: Use Splunk for analysing your logs. It can automatically fetch your logs from remote locations, indexes them, allows you to query them, generate reports with them, etc.